# People whose hair is curly often get their hair straightened. Is this natural?

Tags: sentence-construction

> People whose hair is curly often get their hair straightened.

Is this natural?
or do I need to use 'whose hairs are'?

and if the noun is unaccountable, do I have to use a singular verb even if the subject is a plural noun?

Answer (score 2):

"Whose hair is curly" is natural.  When talking about the overall appearance or style, we use the uncountable "hair"

> His hair is curly. His hair is grey.  His hair is dyed and permed. His hair is straightened.

We would only talk about "hairs" when explicitly referring to particular individual strands, usually in contrast to the overall appearance.

> He has a few white hairs.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! :)